# What would happen if the aether did exist and there was no such thing as relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, speed-of-light, aether

I'm curious as to the purpose of relativity and why the universe would function this way as opposed to a universe with an aether. So what would be different if we had an aether?

Comment: These things are usually addressed properly in the elementary aspects of relativity. I would recommend a traditional special relativity course at university level, which should clear your doubts.

Comment: We would need to find explanations for why our model predictions were all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Brings to mind some thoughts.

After Maxwell published his theory of electromagnetism, many people thought that the EM waves had to be traveling through some medium, so they postulated the ether.  Maxwell's Theory has waves propagating at a characteristic speed, but it was unknown exactly what the speed meant. Was it it speed of source, speed of observation point, speed relative to the ether?

To sort that out, Michelson and Morley used a very sensitive interferometer to see if the speed of light changed if a light beam traveled perpendicular to earth's orbit vs. parallel to the  earth's orbit. No difference in the speed of light was observed.

So that's a jumping off point. If there was an ether, the speed of light would change depending on which direction the light beam was moving.

Length contraction and time dilation logically follow from the universality of the speed of light, so those would change. Consequently there would be significantly fewer muons reaching the surface of the earth from interactions in the upper atmosphere. Other observations would be off from their known values.

Magnetic fields would behave differently. These fields can be represented as an electrostatic field arising from a charge distribution from different times in the past.

Flat earth theorists have to explain many observations presently explained by a round earth theory. For example, they claim gravity is caused by the disc of the earth accelerating upward. This would lead to a gravitational field more uniform than the one we actually have and independent of earth's variable density.

In that same sense and ether would have many implications likely testable that wouldn't hold up.

Suppose there was a robust aether theory avoiding many ad hoc corrections that agreed with experiment and made all the predictions of special relativity. It wouldn't work to supersede special relativity. By virtue of introducing a new phenomena with no additional explaining power it could be ruled out as moot.

Comment: Good answer mostly. But "they are effectively a manifestation of electrostatic field propagating from the past" is a nonsensical and probably incorrect sentence. Better would be something like "they are an electrostatic field in another frame of reference". That is, with the exception of magnetic fields produced by spin (which is frankly most of the magnetic fields ordinary people encounter). But also not all magnetic fields can be transformed into purely electric fields with a suitable Lorentz boost. This really only applies to the magnetic field produced by a straight current carrying wire.

Comment: Good point. I'm trying to figure out the best way to describe electrostatics+ retarded time without complex math.